# convert a list of strings to a c array in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

there are several instructions on how to convert a string to a CString to be passed in a call to C with FFI. My problem is to convert a list of strings to a `char **word` value, for which I cannot find an answer in stackoverflow nor on hackage.

I see one option: I could convert each string from the list with `newCString` and then feed these to newArray - not forgetting to free the reserved memory.

I guess there should be a better option for this relatively common operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think there is anything for this. `newCString` and `newArray` make it simple enough already:

```
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

makeCStringArray :: [[String]] -> IO (Ptr CString)
makeCStringArray arr = newArray =<< traverse newCString arr

freeCStringArray :: Int -> Ptr CString -> IO ()
freeCStringArray n ptr = do
  strs <- peekArray n ptr
  traverse free strs
  free ptr
```

Comment: sounds like a useful abstraction to put somewhere in hackage... I will adapt your code and use it! Thank you!